# Make gdb show thread names on 'apply all' operations

Tags: gdb, pthreads, pretty-print

I'm debugging an app with many threads, so I've named them using prctl. This works great with gdb's `info threads` option, but it would be nice if `thread * apply all` operations showed it as well. Any way to coerce gdb to do this?

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  ...
  3    Thread 0x7ffff6ffe700 (LWP 30048) "poll_uart_threa" 0x00007ffff78eb823 in select ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
  2    Thread 0x7ffff77ff700 (LWP 30047) "signal hander" do_sigwait (set=<optimized out>, 
    sig=0x7ffff77feed8)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/../../../../../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/sigwait.c:65
* 1    Thread 0x7ffff7fcc700 (LWP 30046) "simulator" __lll_lock_wait ()
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:132
```

Pointer, PID {well, thread ID, but LWP threads == processes, ish}, and name

```
(gdb) thread apply all bt
...
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7ffff6ffe700 (LWP 30048)):
#0  0x00007ffff78eb823 in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x0000000000403bb3 in poll_uart_thread (unused=0x0) at uart.c:96
#2  0x00007ffff7bc4e9a in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff6ffe700) at pthread_create.c:308
#3  0x00007ffff78f24bd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff77ff700 (LWP 30047)):
<call stack>
#2  0x0000000000417a89 in sig_thread (arg=0x7fffffffbb60) at simulator.c:879
#3  0x00007ffff7bc4e9a in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff77ff700) at pthread_create.c:308
#4  0x00007ffff78f24bd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:112
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7fcc700 (LWP 30046)):
<call stack>
#9  0x00000000004182e3 in simulator (flash_file=0x7fffffffe0e4 "../programs/blink.bin")
    at simulator.c:1005
#10 0x0000000000401f14 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdd48) at cli.c:167
```

While I can find the name by hunting the call stack, it'd be nice / convenient / etc if it would print in the summary line, which here only has PID and pointer.

Comment: If relevant, I'm running: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2) 7.4-2012.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way, you have to patch GDB. It's a simple patch, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/mildsunrise/48be810f41551ac2049c477dda0879ab).

Answer (score -1):

> it'd be nice / convenient / etc if it would print in the summary line, which here only has PID and pointer.

Please file an ehnancement request in [GDB bugzilla](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb).

If you are using GDB with embedded python, you might be able to [script](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Threads-In-Python.html#Threads-In-Python) "thread apply" to do what you want, but it really ought to do the right thing already.